# Excel is very slow to export to PDF following install of win32com

Tags: python, excel, windows, pdf, win32com

I accidentally installed pywin32 via pip with no virtual environment enabled and ever since, Excel is extremely slow to export to PDF and often crashes when trying to do so. A single 150kB file can take up to 5 minutes to export, the same file used to take about 2 seconds. I am exporting via 'Create PDF/XPS Document'. The issue does occur when exporting from Word.

All of the latest Windows updates for the machine have been installed. I have already tried uninstalling the packages via pip and uninstalling python from the machine but this does not fix the problem (exports are slightly faster though and Excel does not crash as often).

I am using Windows 11 Pro 22621.2506 and Python 3.11.

Any help appreciated, many thanks.